# How to get value per row based on multiple values SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to make a single row per PolicyNumber. But the ClaimStatus is the problem.

If I have more than 1 claimCount, then I need to check if one of the ClaimStatus = 'Open'.

If one of them is 'Open' then value in a `ClaimStatus` need to be `Open` for the whole `PolicyNumber`, otherwise `ClaimStatus = 'Closed'`

Current result looks like this:

```
PolicyNumber    ClaimCount  ClaimStatus
---------------------------------------
Pol1                2        Closed
Pol1                2        Open
Pol2                2        Closed
Pol2                2        Closed
Pol3                1        Closed
Pol4                3        Open
Pol4                3        Closed
```

Sample code:

```
declare @ClaimsTable table (PolicyNumber varchar(50), ClaimCount int, ClaimStatus varchar(50))
insert into @ClaimsTable 
values ('Pol1', 2, 'Closed'), ('Pol1', 2, 'Open'),
       ('Pol2', 2, 'Closed'), ('Pol2', 2, 'Closed'),
       ('Pol3', 1, 'Closed'),
       ('Pol4', 3, 'Open'), ('Pol4', 3, 'Closed')

select * from @ClaimsTable
```

The result should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only two values, you can use `max()`:

```
SELECT policynumber, count(*) AS numclaims,
       MAX(claimstatus)
FROM @ClaimsTable
GROUP BY policynumber;
```

This depends on the fact that `'Open'` > `'Closed'`.  A more general solution might be:

```
SELECT policynumber, count(*) AS numclaims,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN claimstatus = 'Open' THEN 1 ELSE END) > 0
             THEN 'Open'
             ELSE MIN(claimstatus)
        END) AS claimstatus
FROM @ClaimsTable
GROUP BY policynumber;
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is this MAX is gonna be based on? If same PolicyNumber will have 2 claims with different ClaimStatus, which one its gonna pick up?

Comment: @Oleg . . . It calculated the maximum, which would be `'Open'` if one is `'Open'` and the other `'Closed'`.

Comment: Yes. Thanks , my comment was related to first piece of code. max(ClaimStatus)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
   select t.* from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PolicyNumber order by claimstatus desc) rn 
from @ClaimsTable
) t where rn=1
```